# Chat messages saved in firebase database but not able to view in listview

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

For my chat application, I have saved `EditText` data to firebase but not I am not able to display the same in `ListView`.  I am able to see the `EditText` data in Firebase database and I want to retrieve it in a `ListView`. Anybody can help me?

```
public class Chatbox extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private Button btnsend;
    private EditText editText;
    private ListView listView;

    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chatbox);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

        btnsend = findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.typemessage);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listmessages);

        btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                databaseReference.child("Chat").child("Name").push().setValue(editText.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                DatabaseReference chatreference=databaseReference.child("Chat");
                chatreference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        try {
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String chatmsg = snapshot.child("Name").getKey();
                                Toast.makeText(Chatbox.this, "keys " + chatmsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                arrayList.add(chatmsg);
                            }
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Chatbox.this, "Error " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: please post the log of `snapshot.child("Name").getKey();` and you're database structure.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how to I add picture in comment....I am not able attach DB picture

Comment: Alex, I wanted to create chat page for my application. In that when user enter his message then it will store in firebase database but I am unale to show the same in listview.

Comment: Ashish, I have added DB image in description. Please check and help

Comment: Have you tried using value event listener instead of listener for single event?

Comment: No not yet...Please define how and where to use.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference("Chat")
                    .child("Name")
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            List<String> chatMessages = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                try {
                                    String chatMessage = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(dataSnapshot1.getKey()).getValue());
                                    chatMessages.add(chatMessage);
                                } catch (DatabaseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            callback.onFailure(null);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

i guess you want to retrive data not the key:

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            DatabaseReference chatreference=databaseReference.child("Chat");
            chatreference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

         for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String chatmsg = snapshot.child("Name").getValue();
                            Toast.makeText(Chatbox.this, "keys " + chatmsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            arrayList.add(chatmsg);
                        }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

or want you to store both in a array list key and value together?

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the messages to the database with:

```
databaseReference.child("Chat").child("Name")
```

That means you must also read the messages from the same path:

```
databaseReference.child("Chat").child("Name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String chatmsg = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            arrayList.add(chatmsg);
        }
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException()l
    }
});
```

The changes:

- Listen to the same node as you're adding the messages to.
- Removed the nested listener, which is not needed.
- Get the value from each child snapshot, instead of trying to read a non-existing `Name` property.
- Removed the `try...catch` as the default behavior is to write messages to logcat, which is more useful than showing them in a toast.
- Implemented `onCancelled`, because you should never ignore errors.